# Where can I find the documentation on DropLine?

Tags: graphics, options

I watched the video "New in Version 14" and I think I remember seeing something I think was called "DropLine" which was illustrated as an option in a 2D graphic that inserted dashed lines from a point to its values on the axes. For the life of me, I cannot find it in the documentation. I am pretty sure I was not dreaming. If anyone knows about this item, please clue me in. Thanks.

Comment: Link to the [doc page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html).

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

```
Plot[{Sin[x] + x/2, Sin[x] + x}, {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotHighlighting -> Placed["Dropline", 6]]
```